# High Average Request Duration on Digitalocean Load balancer using golang fasthttp

Tags: go, request, digital-ocean, duration, fasthttp

I have a go program which takes requests processes them within 100ms and sends a response. I am using digitalocean Load Balancer and i noticed 'Average Request Duration' is pretty high around 33Kms.Below is the graph

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj9bN.png

Here is the code i am using...

```
count :="one"
n := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {    
switch count {
 case "one":
  handle(ctx)     //...dosomething for 100 ms function   
 default:
  ctx.Error("not found", fasthttp.StatusNotFound)
 }
}
fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8082", n)
```

What am i doing wrong and why isn't my program closing requests.

Comment: You are omitting the relevant code. Add the implementation for `handler`.